# I need to reverse the number and if I enter 0 as the last number it should be replaced as 1

Tags: java

I need to reverse the number and if I enter 0 as the last number it should be replaced as 1. Need help. Can only use while loop.

What should I add to my code?
I can't use arrays.

```
public static void main(String[]args){

        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

        int reversed = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter your number");
        int number = kbd.nextInt();

        while (number > 0){
            int digit = number % 10;
            reversed = 0 * reversed + digit;
            number/=10;
            System.out.println("Reversed number: "+reversed);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Debug and let's us know what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

starting with the obvious

`0 * reversed` give you 0 no matter what, probably not what you want

`System.out.println("Reversed number: "+reversed);` should be outside of the while loop

the logic for your program should be as follow:

1. read final digit of number
2. add the read digit to reversed
3. remove the final digit from number

repeat until no digits remain inside number

EDIT:
I have altered the algorithm to work with a string instead. the basic logic remains the same. only now you are reading chars in a string instead of digits in a number.

```
    public static void main(String[]args){

        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

        String reversed = "";
        System.out.println("Enter your number");
        String number = kbd.nextLine();
        while(!number.equals("")){
            char digit = number.charAt(number.length()-1);
            reversed = reversed+digit;
            number = number.substring(0, number.length() - 1);
        }
        System.out.println("Reversed number: "+reversed);

    }
```

Comment: So I tried your code and when I type a number like 0123 it only shows the 321. How can I fix that?

Comment: that is because you are reading integers from the scanner ("nextInt"). and when 0123 is stored as an int it turns to 123

Comment: what you want isn't sth to reverse a number as 0123 is not, but an algorithm to reverse a string.

Comment: I have updated the answer to work with a string. i.e. input 0123 output 3210; input Hello output olleH